# python3 iterating through dates

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, iteration, timedelta, period

I have a list of date objects X ("%Y,%m,%d") and a date Y and want to have a list Z with all dates in it that are +-10days away from date Y IGNORING the year.

```
Ex.: 
timeDelta = 10days
X = [2017-10-10, 2014-09-31, 1999-05-10, 1992-10-18]
Y = 2019-10-05
Z = MyFunction(X, Y, delta)


MyFunction(X,Y, timeDelta):
for i in range((currentDate-500000),currentDate,10000):  # last 50 years in 1 year steps
     bottomBoundries.append(datetime.strptime(str(i),'%Y%m%d')-timedelta(timeDelta))
     topBoundries.append(datetime.strptime(str(i),'%Y%m%d')+timedelta(timeDelta))
 for i in range(0, pandas.shape[0], 1):
     for j in range(0, len(bottomBoundries) , 1):
            if ((pandas["MESS_DATUM"].iloc[i] > bottomBoundries[j]) & (pandas["MESS_DATUM"].iloc[i] < topBoundries[j])):
                indices.append(i)
 result = pandas.iloc[indices]
return result
```

This takes a lot of time and I was wondering how to make it more efficient.

Comment: Note that '2014-09-31' is not a valid date. Also the first few lines are not the correct syntax in python. You need to write the dates as strings.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [`timetuple().yday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple) to get the day in the year

so something like this might work:

```
def diff_without_year(date, reference_date, timedelta):
    ref_yday = reference_date.timetuple().yday
    diff = d.timetuple().yday - ref_yday # + optionally code to take care of the difference in hours, minutes,...
    return abs(diff) <= timedelta
```

here `timedelta` is in days. If you get it in a `TimeDelta` object, you can convert by dividing by `pd.TimeDelta('1day')`

```
df['result'] = df["MESS_DATUM"].apply(lambda x: diff_without_year(x, ref_date, timedelta))
```

If you have your dates in a `pandas` series, you can simplify this up by using [Series.dt.dayofyear](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html#pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear)

```
df['result'] = (df["MESS_DATUM"].dt.dayofyear - reference_date.timetuple().yday) < timedelta
```

Comment: `'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'yday'`

Answer (score 0):

A more adhoc solution that checks for each date in `X` whether the date in the year of `Y` is within 10 days, as well as the date in the preceding and succeeding year. This runs in linear time in size of `X`. For a large list of `X`, you can adapt this to do it in a pandas dataframe, and parallelize this code.

```
import datetime

timeDelta = 10  # in days
X = ['2017-10-10', '2014-09-30', '1999-05-10', '1992-10-18']
Y = '2019-10-05'
Y_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Y, '%Y-%m-%d')  # convert to datetime
td = datetime.timedelta(timeDelta)
year = Y_date.year

output_dates = []
for date in X:
    X_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    month = X_date.month
    day = X_date.day

    date_previous_year = datetime.datetime(year=year-1, month=month, day=day)
    date_current_year = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)
    date_next_year = datetime.datetime(year=year+1, month=month, day=day)
    if abs(date_previous_year - Y_date) <= td or \
        abs(date_current_year - Y_date) <= td or \
        abs(date_next_year - Y_date) <= td:
        output_dates.append(date)
print(output_dates)
```

Comment: this would only check 3 years. I would need to check the last 50-100 years. so comparing 50-100 timespans with an array of timepoints

Comment: The code converts any date in X to three dates and checks whether any of these dates are within 10 days to Y. For example, consider Y = '2019-10-05' and X = '2017-10-10'. X is then converted to '2019-10-10' (year of Y with the same day and month as in X), '2018-10-10' (year that preceding year of Y) and '2020-10-10'. If any of these dates are within 10 days to '2019-10-05', then it is returned. In this case, '2019-10-05' is within 10 days to '2019-10-05', so it is returned. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes this is what I want and my code does already, yet I wondered if there is a faster way of doing this for a larger set in less time

Comment: @Christian Your code iterates through 50 (or however many) years and computes the boundaries for each year, and then checks for each date in X whether it is in any of the boundaries. In my suggested solution, you don't have to compute the boundaries for 50+ years.

Comment: If you want to find better ways of doing things, CodeReview is probably a better place to post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/